# how to run multiple jobs one after another in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I have scenario, with multiple jobs in jenkins ex: JobA; JobB; JobC; JobD; JobE all are independent of each other; but i want to Run a new job (ex: JobF) in that job i want all the above jobs JobA; JobB; JobC; JobD; JobE to be run one after another.
I Dont want to change pre and post build configs on any jobs( JobA; JobB; JobC; JobD; JobE ) because some time i have to run the jobs independently.

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you should use jenkins build flow plugin

[jenkins build flow plugin](https://dzone.com/articles/build-flow-jenkins-plugin)

Comment: qq, i want to pass the parameter from JobF to all the other jobs... for example in DSL text : build( "jobA", param1:"${param1}" ). can i do something like this.I tried this it wont pass the parameter to any jobs. any suggestions please

Comment: I can't seem to find this plugin? Is it still available?

Comment: Seems like this plugin is deprecated. It's no more available.